# Cache manifest - edited pages not updating

Tags: wordpress, caching, layout

I am working on a website and i have installed the Super cache plugin. I have disabled the plugin and before this is have cleared all cache. But now my website layout has been disturb. Can any one help me?
Website is in dutch language http://blinqz.nl/.

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing you're talking about the boxes that should be in rows of 3.

<strike>This is because each box takes up 297px of space, x 3 = 891. The total width of the parent div is 870 which is where the problem comes in.</strike>

If you add this to you're css it should make the 3rd item on each row lose its right side padding allowing 3 to go on each row

```
ul.products li.product.grid, ul.products li.product.list:nth-child(3n+3) {
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

This problem seems completely unrelated to the super cache plugin.

Looking more into the code, it seems you use a class called last. This has changed from being on the 3rd item to being on the 4th item each time.

Might be a setting in your woocommerce thats changed?